# Using setTimeout with request package in Node.js

Tags: javascript

So I have these codes:

```
Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
  var row = results[key];
  const url =
    "https://api.hypixel.net/player?uuid=" +
    row.dcmc_uuid +
    "&key=" +
    process.env.API;
  var request = require("request");
  request({
      url: url,
      json: true
    },

    function role(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        if (!body.player.rank) {
          if (!body.player.newPackageRank) {
            var rank = "Non";
          } else {
            if (body.player.newPackageRank === "VIP") {
              var rank = "VIP";
            }
            if (body.player.newPackageRank === "VIP_PLUS") {
              var rank = "VIP+";
            }
            if (body.player.newPackageRank === "MVP") {
              var rank = "MVP";
            }
            if (body.player.newPackageRank === "MVP_PLUS") {
              var rank = "MVP+";
            }
            if (body.player.newPackageRank === "MVP_PLUS_PLUS") {
              var rank = "MVP++";
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (body.player.rank === "YOUTUBER") {
            var rank = "Youtuber";
          }
          if (body.player.rank === "ADMIN") {
            var rank = "ADMIN";
          }
        }
        console.log(row.dcmc_dcid + " is " + rank);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

When I do the `forEach()` loop for my database, everything turns undefined after a while.
Is this the Timeout problem?
If so, how can I use `setTimeout()` inside the request package or is there any way I can set a timeout?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is undefined?

Comment: something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047986/javascript-function-variable-all-of-a-sudden-becomes-undefined
However, in my case I am using request and I don't know how to include setTimeout in my code

Comment: Which variables are undefined? Is it possible that you have a typo on the console.log line at the end there? Did you mean `row.dcmc_uuid` instead of `row.dcmc_dcid`?

Comment: `rank` could also be undefined because it doesn’t get defined anywhere in your logic. I don’t know what the API might be returning, but if for example `body.player.rank` was a truthy value other than `'ADMIN'` or `'YOUTUBER'` (such as `'HUMAN'` or `'YouTuber'`) then rank would be undefined.

Comment: Nope, I didn't have a typo. Some records can be shown without getting the undefined error. However, after 7 or 8 records show up, I got the error and the loop stopped.

Comment: What variable is undefined? What is the exact error?